# mongodb findMany by id in all records in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to get from the database objects from each element in the array files, by array of ids `["c5f2d584-60ab-4068-b567-9b422f6c4e24","09c0ef39-55ea-45b4-88d3-a8f97730d6d3"]`.

How to make such a request?

[image]

```
model.find({
    files: '_id' : ["c5f2d584-60ab-4068-b567-9b422f6c4e24","09c0ef39-55ea-45b4-88d3-a8f97730d6d3"]
}).
then(res => {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $in operator like this:

```
model.find({
    "files._id": { $in: ["c5f2d584-60ab-4068-b567-9b422f6c4e24","09c0ef39-55ea-45b4-88d3-a8f97730d6d3"] }
}).
then(res => {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: @Стас Рябцев I am glad it worked for you. I would appreciate if you can also upvote the answer.